# How do I build Lumber Mill in scenario editor

Tags: openttd

No matter what I do, when I'm trying to buld a lumber mill, I always end up with red error:

**[image: Can't build Lumber Mill here - can only be built in rainforest areas.]**

I tried to build hills and trees on them - no effect at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little research, it showed up, that to turn area in rainforest, one has to place a "raiforest" tree on grass. Rainforest trees are these, that cannot be planted near dessert in gameplay:
[image: trees that can create rainforest]

This works inversely in screnario editor. Said trees will generate rainforest area whenever you plant them. Even dessert:
[image: Lumber Mill on dessert]

Persistence of sand under the trees may be a bug.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, your answer is not complete. my answer is correct atleast for some versions ago but for the current version incomplete as well, by combining both answers we have a full answer. Now, like you said, you need to place tree's in the green area's. This can be done within the game by placing your rainforest tree's on the green area's then you can place the lumber mill in the green area some tiles from the edge of the desert tiles. Tested this and worked.

Comment: On the screenshot, there is a Lumber Mill on the yellow (not green) area. This means that, in scenario editor, trees determine whether certain area is or isn't rainforest. Your [original answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/141510/1) stated the countrary. Your edit to the original answer probably sources from this answer.

Comment: Yes, i am combining our answers like i am saying in my previous post. Your answer to this is "breaking" the rules of the game, since rain forest tree's cannot be planted on desert without the scenario editor. My current answer is answering the question in a legit way, plant these rain forest tree's you mention on green tiles, when there is enough room you will be able to plant a lumber mill within normal gameplay.

Comment: You obviously failed to read the question title.

Comment: Is this different for OpenTTD? I've tried all 12 types of tree, and placed them incredibly densely using the "Forest" option, but none seem to be classed as rainforest.

Answer (score -1):

You need to select the sub-tropical climate as a map type. On that map you can only place lumber mills in the pre-designated "green" rain-forest areas. First you need to build rainforest tree's in these green areas. Now you can place a lumber mill a couple tiles off the deserts edge. You might need to bulldoze some industries already placed there to create some room.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, that you're wrong.